# I'm trying to make a random complete NBA generator on vba

Tags: excel, random, numbers, generator, vba

I'm trying to make a random complete NBA generator on vba in excel. I've already made a functioning single team generator by randomly generating a number between 1 and 30 which I match for the team, and the starting five. How can I make a random number generator that doesn't generate a number already generated, so that I don't have 5 bobcats or 5 dwight howards throughout the association? Thanks

Comment: This [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RandomNumbers.aspx) page has a section on generating a list of unique random longs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the returned random number against the database of teams and/or players. If the team/player is not used, accept it and then update the record to indicate that that player/team is now in use.